# How to Subtract Values from Matching Columns in Two Different Pandas DataFrames to find minimum distance using globals

Tags: python, pandas, global

I want to subtract values from matching columns between many data frames in order to find the smallest distance. Best explained with an example

I have the following Dataframes:

```
Pool_Hour_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['BusinessUtc','Horizon','EvaluationUtc','BZ','Value'])
date = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 00:00:00')
day = timedelta(days = 1)
date1 = date
date2 = date - day
date3 = date2 -day
date4 = date3 -day
Horizon = 'D-1'
BZ = ['NO4','NO4','NO4','NO4','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO5','NO5','NO5','NO5']
Values = [1301.681, 1271.479,1460.043, 1302.357,3412.155, 3611.549, 4042.706, 3756.527,1462.085, 4042.706, 3756.527,1462.085]
Pool_Hour_1['EvaluationUtc'] = [date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4]
Pool_Hour_1['BusinessUtc'] = date
Pool_Hour_1['Horizon'] = Horizon
Pool_Hour_1['EvaluationUtc'] = [date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4]
Pool_Hour_1['BZ'] = BZ
Pool_Hour_1['Value'] = Values

forecast_Hour_1 = df_t.drop(index = [1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11])

f1=Pool_Hour_1.assign(Value=Pool_Hour_1['Value'].sub(Pool_Hour_1['BZ'].map(forecast_Hour_1.set_index('BZ')['Value'])))
```

This works great. As an example I am subtracting `Pool_Hour_1 Value` for `BZ == NO4` from the `forecast_Hour_1 Value` from `NO4`. And so forth for all `BZ's`

Now I want to do the same for the next 23 Pool hours where an example of one of the next pool hours can simply be like so:

```
Pool_Hour_2 = Pool_Hour_1
Pool_Hour_2['Value'] = round(Pool_Hour_1.Value /3.4)
f2=Pool_Hour_2.assign(Value=Pool_Hour_2['Value'].sub(Pool_Hour_2['BZ'].map(forecast_Hour_1.set_index('BZ')['Value'])))
```

The desired output is simply a DataFrame of appended values from the f-series i.e.

`df_fin = pd.concat([df_fin,f1,f2,f3...], axis = 0)`

Once I've done that for each of the 24 `Pool_Hour_XX`'s I do the same with `forecast_Hour_2` and `forecast_Hour_3` etc...

The goal is to test each of the forecast hours against each of the pool hours and find the minimum value. I believe it can be done more simply with global variables but I'm not sure I quite understand how in this case.